# Sort XML Schema without reordering children of named element

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

We generate XML Schemas from a model, but we find that this can cause the XML schemas to reorder over time. This isn't something we can easily control, so we intend to apply an XSLT transformation to the generated XML Schemas to give them a more settled order.

To achieve this, we figured reordering the elements based on element name, then attributes (`name` would ideally take precendence over other attributes).

i.e. order by

1. `<element>` (element name)
2. `<element name="xyz">` (attribute 'name')
3. `<element *="*">` (all other attributes)

There is however one set of elements that we cannot re-order the children of, which is `<xs:sequence>` as these are in a strict order.

An example  definition which cannot have order changed is below.

```
  <xs:complexType name="OBJECT.OtherSystemClaimsXref">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:group ref="FIELDS.OtherSystemClaimsXref"/>
      <xs:group ref="FIELDS.ExternallyMaintained"/>
      <xs:group ref="FIELDS.DtoSupplier"/>
      <xs:group ref="FIELDS.BusinessObject"/>
      <xs:group ref="FIELDS.OtherSystemXrefAbstract"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="externalSystemReference" type="TYPE.OpenTwinsExternalReference" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="dataChangedEnum" type="ENUM.DataChangedEnum" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="importable" type="xs:boolean" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
```

I came up with the below XSLT as a starting point.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
                <xsl:sort select="name()" />
                <xsl:sort select="@*" order="ascending" data-type="text" />
                <xsl:sort select="." />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I attempted to alter the behaviour by preventing the sort happening for `<xs:sequence>`, but this did not work.

```
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(local-name()='sequence')]">
                <xsl:sort select="name()" />
                <xsl:sort select="@*" order="ascending" data-type="text" />
                <xsl:sort select="." />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name()='sequence']"/>
        </xsl:copy>
```

How can I apply these rules for everything except the immediate children of `<xs:sequence>`?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the children of `xsl:sequence` to be ordered, you should add a specific template for this which will take priority over your generic one.

```
<xsl:template match="xs:sequence">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This will require you declaring the `xs` namespace prefix in the stylesheet.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
                <xsl:sort select="name()" />
                <xsl:sort select="@*" order="ascending" data-type="text" />
                <xsl:sort select="." />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xs:sequence">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I had to add another `<xsl:template match="xs:complexType">` due to some ordering constraints defined by the XML Schema definition. Ideally I'd like the top level <xs:element> to remain at the top too, but not sure how that could be achieved. It's not a big deal for me.